# Adding delay to java code

Tags: java, delay, thread-sleep

I am making multiple REST API request calls to a third party app from java and I do not know the threshold value of number of requests they procees in a given time and I am thrown a 429 too many requests runtime exception, I need to add a delay between these API calls can anyone suggest an optimal way(there are no threads used in the app)

Comment: you can use thread.sleep. There will be the main thread doing its job. You can use sleep in that main thread.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Handler.postDelayed()` method:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something that is meant to be delayed
    }
}, delayMillis);
```

where `delayMillis` is delay time measured in milliseconds.